# Java Shared Resources stored to wrong path

Tags: java, resources

I have two projects that share a common resource folder. I use this command to access those files:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myResources.xml")
```

This statement returns a path, which is not valid. In fact it returns:

> project/shared-resources/target/classes/myResource.xml

but it should return

> project/shared-resources/src/main/resource/myResource.xml

During the build process, all resources are copied to this target/classes path, so I am able to load those files, but changed are overwritten which is not wanted.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Please clarify _changed are overwritten_.

Comment: Also, you have to start differentiating between your source folders/files and your compiled files and resources.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I change the content of the loaded resources, the next build process will just overwrite the files in project/shared-resources/target/classes/myResource.xml with the once in project/shared-resources/src/main/resource/myResource.xml

Comment: Resources are **not** meant to be written to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `getClass().getClassLoader()` will load resources from your *class* path.

> project/shared-resources/src/main/

The above is your source path - no class files.

When you compile and run your application, classes are compiled to (and loaded from):

> project/shared-resources/target/classes/

In your IDE (assuming you're using one), it's usually trivial to add a resource (your `resource/myResource.xml` file) into your build process, so that it's copied to the target into the same structure.

If / when your deploy / distribute your application, you'll need to do this as the `src` path won't typically be included in your jar, ear or war file etc.

Comment: And how do I access the source path?

Comment: It's not part of your built application, so you either choose to load it from the filesystem (not as a relative classpath resource) or include it in your build (and have one project have the other as a library dependency).